# How to downgrade Python 3.8.8 to 3.7.9 in anacoda (windows 10)

Tags: python, anaconda

How to downgrade Python 3.8.8 to 3.7.9 in anacoda (windows 10)

conda create -n new_env python=3.6
conda activate new_env

Comment: You cannot "downgrade" python. You can install another interpreter, though

Comment: Looks like you have both question and answer in both question and answer. Remove question from answer and answer from question.

Answer (score 0):

How to downgrade Python 3.8.8 to 3.7.9 in anacoda (windows 10)

---

conda create -n new_env python=3.7.9
conda activate new_env